# JUDDI: (/juddiv3/services) is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, uddi, juddi

after installing juddi server as described here
http://thoughtsasaservice.wordpress.com/tag/juddi/
I can enter to the main interface here:

```
http://localhost:8181/juddiv3/
```

But when I click on (View service listing) I find 404 error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /juddiv3/services
type: Status report
message: /juddiv3/services
description: The requested resource (/juddiv3/services) is not available.
```

Moreover, when I enter to

```
http://localhost:8181/pluto/portal/jUDDI
```

I found this error:

```
 Error rendering portlet.

org.apache.pluto.PortletContainerException: Unable to obtain the servlet context for the portlet app context path [/uddi-portlets]. Make sure that the portlet app has been deployed, and that cross context support is enabled for the portal app.
    at org.apache.pluto.core.PortletContainerImpl.getPortletAppContext(PortletContainerImpl.java:429)
    at org.apache.pluto.core.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.tags.PortletTag.doStartTag(PortletTag.java:152)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.themes.portlet_002dskin_jsp._jspx_meth_pluto_005fportlet_005f0(portlet_002dskin_jsp.java:105)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.themes.portlet_002dskin_jsp._jspService(portlet_002dskin_jsp.java:79)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.themes.pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp.java:472)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.themes.pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp.java:428)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.themes.pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp.java:389)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.themes.pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp._jspService(pluto_002ddefault_002dtheme_jsp.java:227)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.PortalDriverServlet.doGet(PortalDriverServlet.java:151)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please advice.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says not all jUDDI's webapplications were deployed successfully.
Check catalina.out because there might have more problems before the one you posted.

Keep in mind jUDDI is very sensitive to its underlying software such as JDK, MySQL and Tomcat.

Make sure you have EXACTLY the same versions as described in http://thoughtsasaservice.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/how-to-install-juddi-on-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest downloading the prepackaged version from the Apache jUDDI web site. The latest version (3.1.5) works, however I don't think the portlets work.

Alternatively, you can grab the source code from the trunk and build 3.2, which has a brand new user interface.

Edit: if the splash page works, and the service listing doesn't, it could indicate that you're using a different soap stack (other than Apache CXF). If that's true, the listing of services it probably at a different url.